Different cells according to the ComboBox Value
Private Sub CSave_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Variable Definition
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long, lr4 As Long, lr5 As Long, lr6 As Long
    
    ' Last Row definitions
    With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
        lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lr3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lr4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lr5 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lr6 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    ' Ensure all last rows are the same
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(lr1, lr2, lr3, lr4)

    ' Debug statements
    Debug.Print "Last Row for F: " & lr1
    Debug.Print "Last Row for G: " & lr2
    Debug.Print "Last Row for H: " & lr3
    Debug.Print "Last Row for K: " & lr4
    Debug.Print "Last Row for O: " & lr5
    Debug.Print "Last Row for S: " & lr6
    Debug.Print "Max Last Row: " & lr

    ' UserForm to Cells with validation
    With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
        If IsNumeric(CTextBox1.Value) Then .Range("F" & lr1).Value = CDbl(CTextBox1.Value)
        If IsNumeric(CTextBox2.Value) Then .Range("G" & lr2).Value = CDbl(CTextBox2.Value)
        If IsNumeric(CTextBox3.Value) Then .Range("H" & lr3).Value = CDbl(CTextBox3.Value)
        .Range("J" & lr4).Value = 7.5
    End With
    
    If CaseTypeC.Value = "Retail" Then
        With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox4.Value) Then .Range("O" & lr5).Value = CDbl(CTextBox4.Value)
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox5.Value) Then .Range("T2").Value = CDbl(CTextBox5.Value)
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox6.Value) Then .Range("T3").Value = CDbl(CTextBox6.Value)
        End With
    ElseIf CaseTypeC.Value = "Vend" Then
        With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox4.Value) Then .Range("S" & lr6).Value = CDbl(CTextBox4.Value)
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox5.Value) Then .Range("W2").Value = CDbl(CTextBox5.Value)
            If IsNumeric(CTextBox6.Value) Then .Range("W3").Value = CDbl(CTextBox6.Value)
        End With
    End If
    
    ' Clear UserForm fields
    With Me
        .CTextBox1.Value = ""
        .CTextBox2.Value = ""
        .CTextBox3.Value = ""
        .CTextBox4.Value = ""
        .CTextBox5.Value = ""
        .CTextBox6.Value = ""
    End With
    Me.CTextBox1.SetFocus

    With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
        ' AutoFill for Closed Volume(cm^3)
        .Range("B7").Formula = "=ClosedVolumeCm3(C7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("B7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B7:B" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Closed Volume(mm^3)
        .Range("C7").Formula = "=ClosedVolumeMm3(G7,H7,I7,J7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("C7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C7:C" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Current Average Density Product Fill(%)
        .Range("D7").Formula = "=CurrentAverageDensityProductFill(F7, B7, $Q$2)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D7:D" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Current Product Fill at Lowest Density(%)
        .Range("E7").Formula = "=CurrenProductFillAtLowestDensity(F7, B7, $Q$3)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("E7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("E7:E" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Max PDQ(mm)
        .Range("I7").Formula = "=MaxPDQ(G7,H7,J7,$K$2,$K$3)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("I7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("I7:I" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Aim PDQ(mm)
        .Range("K7").Formula = "=AimPDQ(G7,I7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("K7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("K7:K" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Effect Bag Length(mm)
        .Range("L7").Formula = "=EffectBagLengthMm(H7,I7,J7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("L7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("L7:L" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Effect Bag Width(mm)
        .Range("M7").Formula = "=EffectBagWidthMm(I7,G7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("M7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M7:M" & lr)
        End If

        ' AutoFill for Lw/Ratio
        .Range("N7").Formula = "=LWRatio(H7,G7)"
        If lr > 7 Then
            .Range("N7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("N7:N" & lr)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' AutoFill for CaseTypeC "Retail"
    If CaseTypeC.Value = "Retail" Then
        With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
            ' AutoFill for Standup # Bags/CS
            .Range("P7").Formula = "=StandUpBagsCs(G7, I7, L7, O7, T$2$, T$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("P7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("P7:P" & lr)
            End If
            
            ' AutoFill for Side Pack # Bags/CS
            .Range("Q7").Formula = "=SidePacksBagsCs(H7, I7, J7, M7, O7, T$2$, T$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("Q7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("Q7:Q" & lr)
            End If
            
            ' AutoFill for Multi-Laye # Bags/CS
            .Range("R7").Formula = "=MultiLayerBagsCs(C7, G7, O7, T$2$, T$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("R7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R7:R" & lr)
            End If
        
        End With
    ElseIf CaseTypeC.Value = "Vend" Then
        
        With Sheets("Lays Confirmed")
            
            ' AutoFill for Standup # Bags/CS
            .Range("T7").Formula = "=StandUpBagsCs(G7, I7, L7, S7, W$2$, W$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("T7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("T7:T" & lr)
            End If
            
            ' AutoFill for Side Pack # Bags/CS
            .Range("U7").Formula = "=SidePacksBagsCs(H7, I7, J7, M7, S7, W$2$, W$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("U7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("U7:U" & lr)
            End If
            
            ' AutoFill for Multi-Laye # Bags/CS
            .Range("V7").Formula = "=MultiLayerBagsCs(C7, G7, S7, W$2$, W$3$)"
            If lr > 7 Then
                .Range("V7").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("V7:V" & lr)
            End If
        
        End With
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
End Subype here

I am trying to change destinaton of the "Case Size" values accourding to the Case types which are located inside the ComboBox which is CaseTypeC. I want them to fill Vend part if I choose vend on ComboBox or I want them to fill retail part if I choose retail. I tried some stuff but they didn't seem to work. I can get the "CTextBox4.Value", "CTextBox5.Value" and "CTextBox6.Value" to cells the code doesn't seem to work when the AutoFill part appears.

I dont really understand what you are asking.  Could you add a bit more to where things aren't working and a bit more about the result you are trying to achieve?

I am trying to change cells destinations of CTextBox4,5 and 6 accordingto the values of CaseTypeC. If CaseTypeC = "Vend" TextBox values will go to vend part Else If CaseTypeC = "Retail" values will go to retail part and the rest of the columns will be autofilled. now there aren't any problems when it comes to  the CTextBox destinations. However, the Autofill part - starting form the "If CaseTypeC.Value = "Retail" Then" line - of the code doesn't work

I'll have a look, one thing i did notice.  Columns O and S are not in the max for last row.

Is it a typo that you define cell references in this way W$2$, W$3$ this must be $W$2, $W$3

You can use (eg) .Range("B7:B" & lr).Formula = "=ClosedVolumeCm3(C7)" no need for autofill: Excel will adjust the formula as needed.

Your code has the comment "Ensure all last rows are the same" but following code seems to assume they may all be different?  Maybe you can explain a bit around that?
